# Дайте IDE для страрого андроида 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio

Захотел написать простую программульку под андроид, но мой компьютер не переварил Android Studio, она говорит что я нищеброд и на таком дешевом компьютере отказывается запускаться.

Но у меня возник вопрос, ведь как-то же разрабатывали проги до появления этого чуда техники - андроид студии.

Конкретно - как и на чем можно по-старинке разрабатывать на Андроид 4.1.

Comment: ну до появления этого чуда техники использовали вроде [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-android-developers/neonm6)

Comment: @CookieMnstr, интересно, а сейчас ей кто-то пользуется?) Я ведь начинал в Eclipse, но как-то запустил AS и не смог вернуться... Может такие гуру как ЮрийСПб и pavlofff помнят момент моих мучений с Gradle (и, в кончном итоге, все мне тут сказали: - "Иди в Android Studio!") :D.

Comment: @RostislavDugin да небось такие как автор вопроса и пользуются, ну и олдфаги какие-нибудь. Я eclipse даже не застал, сразу с AS начал.

Comment: под какую версию андроид собирать проект в данном случае никак не скажется на затратах ресурсов компьютера. То есть, что под андроид 2.1 что под 7.0, ресурс от компьютера разработчика потребуется одинаковый.

Answer (score 2):

Не мучайтесь с Eclipse и Vim (если Вы не претендуете на звание гуру, конечно), а просто включите [энергосберегающий режим](https://hedgehogjim.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/android-studio-power-save-mode/) в Android Studio, который отключит много полезных, но "тяжелых" функций.

---

Так же не помешает установить легковесную систему. Лично я ставил Debian 8 с граф. оболочкой LXDE. Все работает прекрасно, удобно и весьма практично. По сравнению с Windows ест намного меньше ресурсов ПК. На моем старом компьютере 
с 3 гигабайтами оперативной памяти DDR2 на 800Мгц, под Windows сборка грузила все на 100% и компьютер ставал практически недоступным, а на Debian - даже музыка в браузере играла почти без прерываний!

---

А вообще, подумайте над обновлением компьютера. По факту, Android Studio нужно не так и много: процессора Intel Core i3, 4 гигабайта памяти типа DDR3 1333Мгц и SSD диска на 180 гигабайт (система + все остальное) хватит для комфортной работы.

---

Кстати, SSD диск очень сильно ускоряет работу. Вчера нужно было перекинуть систему на старый HDD 5200 об\с со всеми проектами и программами. Так вот одновременная загрузка IDEA и Android Studio заняла в районе 10-15 минут (по сравнению с 1-2 на SSD). Сейчас поставил Debian и XFCE и все вернулось к нормальной скорости (если интересует, ноутбук с процессором Intel Core i3 2-го поколения, 10 гигабайт ОЗУ DDR3 1333Мгц и SSD диск на 240 под систему и программы).

Answer (score 1):

IDE не является обязательной вещью для разработки. IDE просто облегчает некоторые действия.

Для разработки вы можете использовать любой редактор кода (vim, emacs, atom и т.п.), Android SDK и настроенную систему сборки проекта (gradle).

Но вам понадобится потратить намного больше времени на изучение правильной структуры проекта и пр. вещей, которые за вас делает IDE.

Comment: Серьзено?) Конечно, так можно, но одно лишь автозаполнение и указание на ошибки экономит невероятно много времени. Большой проект так не понянуть, маленький будет очень неудобно тянуть, а для автора вопроса, по всей видимости, нереально (хотя все когда-то такому учаться). Так что этот ответ из разряда: Вы можете пойти по такому-то пути, но потратите 10 лет и, скорее всего, Вас загрызут медведи или убьют разбойники  :)).

Comment: @RostislavDugin я знаком с людьми которые работают в vim и довольны. и проект у них довольно большой. автозаполнение в vim настраивается, наличие тестов позволяет сэкономить на отладке.

Comment: Но, тем не менее, обилие функций IDEA значительно упрощают жизнь, а для неопытного человека - практически спасают.

Comment: @RostislavDugin я знаю. последнее предложение в моем ответе как раз про это.

Comment: @RostislavDugin кстати, говорить человеку, что он имеет физические недостатки не корректно. даже, если вы поставили в конце смайлик. рекомендую воздерживаться от подобных аргументов.

Comment: Я никому такого и не говорил, между прочим. Я провел явно преувеличенную аналогию и никак не пытался никого этим обидеть...

Comment: @RostislavDugin вы это написали. ваша аналогия не уместна в рамках уважительной беседы.

Comment: Если Вы все-таки обратили на это внимание, данное предложение можно рассматривать как литературный прием, что не являет собой что-либо оскорбительное. И, как я писал Выше,  никакого конкретного человека никак и ничем не оскорблял (и даже не мог подумать об этом). И чего Вы так ополчились на маленькую шутку (заметьте, что в "рамках уважительной беседы" это выглядит страннее, чем шутка)?

Comment: @RostislavDugin А идеальных людей вообще нет, у всех свои "тараканы", один слово "слепой" не может видеть, другой возмущается когда задают вопрос в комментариях вместо вопроса, третий не переносит тех кто рекомендует Objective-C когда есть более новый Swift... а четвертый и вовсе свастику на стенке рисует.

Comment: @Rou1997, это Вы к чему?

Answer (score 1):

У меня Eclipse+ADT в качестве основной.
То есть устанавливается Eclipse, причем старой версии, у меня Juno, а то тоже будет работать медленно, на него плагин ADT, отдельно Android SDK и Android NDK (если нужен), если нужен Gradle - тоже отдельно устанавливается, мне он обычно не нужен.
В ней в принципе можно разрабатывать все то же, что в Android Studio, включая работу с support библиотеками - appcompat-v7, design (это для Material).
И собирать не только для 4.1, но и хоть для 7.0. Это вам не Apple, чтобы были ограничения подобного рода.
Но для того, чтобы заставить в ней работать эти библиотеки, нужен аналитический склад ума и декомпозиционное мышление, проще говоря "прямые руки", что приходит не сразу, а также понадобилась Android Studio, чтобы скопировать их из нее.
Ее (и Gradle) я запускаю на VPS, когда она нужна.
Собственно с помощью VPS мог бы постоянно работать с Android Studio, передачу APK как-нибудь настроил бы, но оно не стоит того, недостатки Eclipse - это мелочи по сравнению с действительно серьезными проблемами, которые у меня возникают и решение которых вне компетенции создателей любой IDE, по крайней мере - они так считают.

Comment: А весьма интересный подход взять VDS и использовать ее. Разве что нужно очень высокое подключение, чтобы картинка была в реальном времени без тормозов. Да и передача делается силой одного-двух скриптов на Linux'e, который напишет и новичек. Но, как по мне, это требует больших затрат, потому что машинка нужна сильная, интернет быстрый, а трафик большой. Проще обновить компьютер.

Comment: @RostislavDugin Очень высокое подключение только для VNC, а он нужен только если VPS на Linux, у меня Windows Server, для Windows-Windows есть родной RDP, работает с любым подключением и так быстро и удобно, что можно перепутать с настоящим. :) Затраты не так велики, 3-5 тысяч рублей в месяц за глаза, а скорее 1.5-2, это дешевле, чем обновить компьютер если это ноутбук, но для меня Eclipse еще дешевле.

Comment: Для нормальной работы AS докупить, к примеру, 4гб ОЗУ + SSD а это в районе 5 тысяч рублей.

Comment: @RostislavDugin Где такие цены? ЦП 3.4 ГГц 3 ядра, ОЗУ 4 ГБ, SSD 40 ГБ, Windows Server 2016, и того 1800 рублей в месяц. Поставил 20 ГБ SSD, это минимум, стало 1500 рублей. А еще я для Apple разрабатываю, так там у меня бесплатно VPS, так и не отключили за неуплату. :) А еще есть идея обмана тестовых периодов, кто знает, кто-то предпочтет ее развить чем ПК новый. :)

Comment: @RostislavDugin А за 5000, это Chromium можно собирать из исходного кода!

Comment: Цена я прикинул примерно. Но суть Вы поняли. За 2-3 месяца окупиться. Про Chromium не понял, поясните.

Comment: @RostislavDugin Его исходный код, это несколько гигабайт, поэтому конфигурация нужна: 8 ядер по 3.4 ГГц, ОЗУ 16 ГБ и SSD 100 ГБ. Я, в свою очередь, не понял, что у вас и чем окупится за 2-3 месяца.

Comment: Ужас! Вы где взяли такие ужасные цифры! Какие несколько гигабайт! Проект нормально соберется и на конфигурации куда более слабой конфигурации (например, которую я примел в своем ответе)! А окупиться, может не совсем правильно выразился, в том смысле, что за 2-3 месяца Вы потратите ту сумму, которую потратили бы на одноразовое обновление железа, а потом и продолжите тратить. Обновление дешевле аренды. Намного.

Comment: @RostislavDugin Мы об одном и том же говорим? Я о браузере Google Chromium, его исходный код не менее двух гигабайт весит, это tarball, а если использовать рекомендуемый способ - depot_tools - то десяток гигабайт скачивается. Вот 5000 руб, это для его сборки. А для обычных проектов хватит упомянутого конфига за 1800 руб.

Comment: @RostislavDugin В ноутбуке не очень обновите процессор, бывает что и совсем не обновите, поскольку именно у вас впаян (или установлен) самый мощный из всех поддерживаемых данным ноутбуком, или же есть проблемы, а в их отсутствии можно убедиться только после его замены, которая денег стоит, если не самому конечно.

Comment: Процессор играет куда менее важную роль, чем память (как ОЗУ, так и ПЗУ) в данном случае. Автору же не нужно моментально собирать громадные проекты, а нужно добиться комфортной работы. И, довольно часто, в ноутбуках можно заменить процессор (мой i3 заменается на i7).

Answer (score 0):

Предложу навскидку 3 варианта:

1. Берете более-менее любой редактор с поддержкой подсвечивания Java синтаксиса и собираете с командной строки через maven или еще лучше Gradle
2. Берете облачный IDE, например мне нравится [Codenvy](https://codenvy.com/) - там увы нет Gradle, зато есть maven, поддерживает почти все - даже отладку. Временами глючит, но вполне терпимо.
3. Разоряетесь на какой-нибудь старенький ультрабук с SSD диском - посмотрите в сторону Samsung 900 или Dell NPX - 4-5 летние вполне можно купить за 20 тыс. деревянных. У меня Samsung 9 серии, выпуска страшно сказать, 2010 года, вполне тянет (с апгрейдом оперативки до 8 гигов)